# undefined method 'each' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
user = User.create!( name:"test", email:"test@test.com" )
```

I'm trying to use Rspec to compare JSON.parse(response.body) to user

when I try user.to_json

i get the error
    undefined method 'each' for #User:0x007f9f9b1fdb98

Comment: Can you add your rspec test code?

Comment: even without the test i get the error when i try to .to_json a user. i even tried following https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json and i get the same error following konata = User.find(1)
  konata.to_json
  # => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
        "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true}  converting any active record object using .to_json gives me this error

Comment: Well did you somehow overwrite the to_json method?
Or where do you have a `.each` placed? please show us some more code like the User model

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot run `each` on a single instance, it has to be an array or enumerable of some kind.

Comment: ah ... its because of enumerable which was included in the User class, when i comment that out i dont get the error .. seems off though